# Highlight Cells Returning True For Countifs

Tags: excel

I have a sheet with 10k+ rows that I get every day.  I have about 50 formulae that I run against this sheet to count certain occurrences, and example of this is

=COUNTIFS(B:B,"*.jpg")

But as well as returning the totals I want the sheet to highlight every row that has been counted.

I thought I could maybe to that with conditional formatting but I cannot get it to work.

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: What version of Excel are you using? In 2010 you can go `Home > Conditional Formatting > Highlight Cell Rules > Text That Contains` and put in `jpg`.

Comment: Thanks, yes it is 2010, is it possible to do that for more than one row as some of the countifs check two columns and they also look for more than one result.  Also can you export/import this type of rule as it will be very time consuming have to set them up every day.

Comment: You can use `Home > Conditional Formatting > New Rule > Use a formula to determine which cells to format` and in there use an `AND` or `OR` formula. No way to import/export as far as im away, better off just hitting record a macro before setting up the conditional formatting and run that each day if its a new sheet.

Comment: will you ever be checking something other than *.jpg?  if you have the *.jpg or just jpg sitting in a cell it can be set up to change depending on what you are counting.  As for import/export, if you set this up on a blank spreadsheet and save it, you could copy and paste you new data into and your conditional formatting will be there and ready to go.  Though I think I prefer the recorded macro method that Tim is suggesting.

Comment: Thanks both - one of the more complex formulae is:  =COUNTIFS(F:F,"G_NOT",D:D,{"FILE","VALID"})  How would I do that using the above solution?   Not sure of the syntax for the conditional formatting formulae.

Answer (score 1):

I have attached a snap shot of an example sheet where the rows are colour banded using conditional formatting.

[image: Example Sheet]

The rule I used to validate if formatting applies has to equate to TRUE.  I test my rule off to the side in cell E1 in this case.  I can also copy it across to make sure I have the $ in the right spot.  When its doing what I want and evaluating to TRUE or FALSE in the right spots, I edit the cell and copy the formula.  I then highlight the range I want to apply it to, in this case A1 to B7 (though technically we can adjust later), and I make sure that A1 is the active cell in the selection.  Then I go to the Home Ribbon and select conditional formatting and get the pop up window below:

[image: Formatting Rules]

You can select all the formatting options for when things are true by left clicking the "Format..." button.

As per Tim's s comment, select the last one from the rule type list "Use a formula...".  in the blank bar below paste your rule that will equate to TRUE or FALSE.  so in our case the rule I used was:

```
=ISNUMBER(SEARCH($C$1,$A1))
```

Basically I am doing a non case sensitive search in cell A for the criteria in C.  IF cell A1 has it, it will return a number.  ISNUMBER will check that its a number and return TRUE.  If it could not find C1 in cell A1 then it would return an error and ISNUMBER would come out false.

[image: Rule manager]

Finally we can see where the rule will apply.  So if you have 10K rows, it may be easier to simply type in the number of the last row here instead of selecting it manually, though that would still work.

I created 1 colouring rule for each file type I was searching for.

### UPDATE

I am not familiar with how your internal array of {"File","VALID"} works, but I am going to assume that you want to count them if column D is equal to one OR the other AND column F is equal to "G_NOT".  In this case since those are the only words in the appropriate cell I will not use the search method and instead just use the following as your formula rule for conditional formatting:

=AND($F1="G_NOT",OR($D1="FILE",$D1="VALID"))

This assumes there is no header row and your data starts in row 1.  If you have a header row change change those 1 to 2.  Have your left most Cell to your right most cell selected with the left most cell being the active cell.  Then go into your conditional formatting.  When you are done you can manage your rules, and adjust your range to go to the last row.

Comment: Bare with me a moment while I come up with the formula to suite your case.  in the meantime let us know if you have further questions about conditional formatting...oh and what columns will the row colouring cover? IE B to K?  I am assuming you dont want to go full width of the worksheet and colour columns you are not using.

Comment: Thanks, I will try this later today and report back.  I don't mind about different colours or which column is highlighted etc I just need to know which rows are not counted by any of my countifs, ie if anyone falls outside my rules and is therefore not being counted.

Comment: Ok, well the above approach essentially does the exact opposite.  It colours only the one being counted by your IF.  So it would be the ones without any background colours that you would want to look for.  I was under the impression that you would be doing multiple counts for different criteria...oh the can of worms I am forseeing.  If you only need to check one counts criteria, then you can surround the whole formula with NOT(insert formula) to highlight the opposite.  Without know more about your counting and your sheet layout I cant really recommend more than the single case.

Comment: No this is helpful as I can just scroll through the rows to find anything not highlighted, so it will just take a couple of minutes which I am OK with thanks.